# Opening Sqlite DB encrypted using SQLite Encryption Extension with DB Browser with SqlCipher

Tags: sqlite, encryption, sqlcipher

I have a database I encrypted using SQLite Encryption Extension being used with MobileServiceSQLiteStore.

Is there anyway to use DB Browser with SqlCipher to view the database. I have the key that was used to decrypt the database.

Answer (score 0):

No, SQLCipher is not compatible with the SQLite Encryption Extension. You may be able to use a command line shell compiled with SQLite Encryption Extension support to open the database.

Comment: Yeah seems to match what I am finding. It looks like SqlCipher just encrypts the pages while SEE encrypts the while file.

Comment: They actually work in a similar way. The whole file is encrypted with both systems. Both encrypt on a per-page level, because SQLite databases are structured that way. However, the key derivation and encryption algorithms used differ.